# Why there's a total index number of arrays in concat result

Tags: javascript, arrays

> ```
> var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
> var b = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
> var c = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
> var d = [a, b, c];
> for (e in d) var f = d.concat(e);
> console.log(f); //[Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], "2"]
> ```

Why there's *2* in there? How to remove that *2*, before the result come out? (not alter the result)

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the objective?

Comment: the objective is knowledge, because https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in stated it's best to use `for.. in` for obects, so I did, and I don't expect the result because I gave no "2" value anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"2"` is the `length` property of the resulting array. It is included, because you loop using `for ... in`. If you use `for (var i=0; i<d.length; i++) {...}`, it will not be included. See snippet. Anyway, it seems to me that you could simplify the whole enchillada using `var f = d.slice()`.

Citing [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.
>   Because the order of iteration is implementation-dependent, iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.prototype.forEach() or the for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where the order of access is important.

[See also ...](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-problem-with-for-in-and-javascript-arrays.html)

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var c = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
var d = [a, b, c];
var f = [];
for (var i=0; i < d.length; i+=1) {
   f.push(d[i]);
}
document.querySelector("#result").textContent = JSON.stringify(f, null, " ");
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Does this mean `for...in` bad for iterating? what makes it different from `for (...)` ?

Comment: @JigongBagong: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @JigongBagong Here's an another excellent  refrence explaining that. and much more... [Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Comment: That's wrong. `for..in` iterates through **enumerable** properties. AFAIK Array's `length` is not enumerable (at least in most engines). In the OP's example `2` is the last key (index) of the `d` array accessed in `for..in` loop.

Comment: this answer fit my question, I just curious and stacked on why there's `2` in there. These answers also useful, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489666/why-theres-a-total-index-number-of-arrays-in-concat-result/31489711#31489711) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489666/why-theres-a-total-index-number-of-arrays-in-concat-result/31489753#31489753)

Comment: @hindmost so this is not the right answer for "why there's `2` in there?"

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your concat operation, here e is the index of element in array d,
Try the code below you will get an idea

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var c = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
var d = [a, b, c];
var f ;
for (e in d){
    console.log(e);
    f = d.concat(e);
    console.log(f);
}
console.log(f); //[Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], "2"]
```

Still it is not clear what output you are expecting.

---

**Edit 1** 
Expected output is d array. As you already defined two dimentional array d having all above there is no need to concate it.

```
console.log(d);
```

---

**Edit 2**
If you what to copy array using this code there is wayaround

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var c = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
var d = [a, b, c];
var f = [];
for (e in d){
    console.log(e);
    f[e] = d[e];
    console.log(f);
}
console.log(f); //[Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]
```

Above code will copy array d in array f

Comment: I expect `[[Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]` because I've given no '2' value in there

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on other answers, you now know the reasoning behind why "2" in your array.

I am trying to target your actual problem and I might be hypothetical, however, it seems you want to concatenate 3 arrays.

If my understanding is correct, you can try

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var c = ['g', 'h', 'i'];
var f = a.concat(b).concat(c);
console.log(f); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
```

Comment: yes the example is with 3 arrays, but what if the number of array is dynamic via `.push()` that's why I use `for..in`

Comment: You just need to update the code, the same way you would have done to update `var d = [a, b, c];` in case of dynamic number of arrays.

Comment: well I thought I could done it via `for in` Thanks for sharing! I really appreciate